# Deactivating Viber Account on my stolen device

Tags: viber-messenger

Is there any possible way to deactivate viber account on my stolen device.? I've tried to open it on PC but it keeps on asking for the code that was sent to my stolen device.. Wondering if deactivating SIM Card will help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Viber support page](https://support.viber.com/customer/portal/articles/1335420-deactivate-your-viber-account-mobile-#.VkDEynorKX5)

> You may re-install Viber on your new device using the old device’s
>   phone number. This will reinstate the previous account on your new
>   device. Please note that message and call history will not be
>   restored.

I would suggest going to the closest avaible store of your service provider and getting a new SIM card with the same number and cancel the stolen one.

Hope this helps!